# DotNetCore WebAPI Dependency Injection Scope and Disposal

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a dot net core 2.0 web api.  The API is using JWT authorization and generally returns json responses.

I am injecting the database context into a repository and then the repository into the controller constructor and it works fine for single requests.

In Startup.cs I have registered the repository and the context as follows:

```
services.AddMvc();
services.AddDbContext<SPContext>(cfg => cfg.UseSqlServer(_config["SPConnectionString"]));
services.AddScoped<ISPRepository, SPRepository>();
```

The repository constructor:

```
private SPContext _context { get; }
public SPRepository(SPContext context, ILogger<SPRepository> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

The Controller constructor:

```
private static ISPRepository _repository;
public ChartsController( ILogger<ChartsController> logger, ISPRepository repository)
{
        _repository = repository;
        _logger = logger;    
}
```

In my method, I have:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/v1/charts/dashboard/my")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyDashboards()
    {
        SPUser user = _repository.GetUserByOid(this.User.Identity.Name);
        return Ok(_repository.GetMyDashboards(user));
    }
```

For a single GET request to this method, I get a result with no errors and if I wait for execution to finish before sending the next request, it works well too.

During testing, I happened to have more than one request fire off at the same time to this route.  The result is a response for the first one and then '500' errors for the rest.

The error log shows the error as:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

However, if I inject the repository into the method, rather than the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/charts/dashboard/my")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyDashboards([FromServices]ISPRepository _repository)
    {
        SPUser user = _repository.GetUserByOid(this.User.Identity.Name);
        return Ok(_repository.GetMyDashboards(user));
    }
```

Then the requests all succeed, even if fired off simultaneously.

My understanding was that objects registered as scoped were available only for the life of a single request and that a new instance would be created when the new request enters the system.  So, from my understanding, the second request should have resulted in a new set of objects being created.

Is there a problem with the way I am registering the services or the controllers?  Or is this the intended behavior of the dependency injection?

Comment: this might probably have something to do with the async as well. is this your complete code for `GetMyDashboards` without any `await` or is it shortened?

Comment: Hi @NevilleNazerane I have tried both.  I made the GetMyDashboards method async and called it with an await but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the 'static' attribute on your _repository in your controller. Because it means all instances of your controller will share a same repository.

When you fire a second request while the first is still being processed,
you will create a new instance of your controller, with a new instance of the repository. That is fine, but because _repository is static, it will be also be shared with the first instance of your controller, by replacing the one previously created.

Both controllers will then call the same underlying DbContext, causing your issue.

When you inject the repository manually, everything is separated, that's why it works well for you.

A good practice is to make your attributes readonly, to ensure they are only initialized once in the constructor, and cannot be overriden later.

```
private readonly ISPRepository _repository;
```